# how to add child element in navigationdrawer with expandble listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

please help me i am new in android development i have created a navigation drawer and now i want to add child element in this how can i add.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    getString(R.string.title_section5),
                    getString(R.string.title_section6),
                    getString(R.string.title_section7)
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

i want to add sub element of these element

Comment: could you be bit more clear please, you mean to add some view in list or something else?

Comment: you can go through this nice tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: ya i want add more sub items inside main items thanks sir for for giving this link information now i hoping i will do that if i will get any problem again i will contact u thanks..

Comment: actually i want add subelement inside main element in which i have facing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways 1st one is explained in comment by @Sharanbasu Angadi - i.e. using menu resources explained in detail in this tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

The 2nd option is important if you want to customise the listview item and headers, use `ExpandableListView` inside `NavigationView` as explained in below code.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_main"
            />


        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_explistview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nav_header_main"/>


    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.webege.rivu.navmenuexpandablelistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.webege.rivu.navmenuexpandablelistview.adapters.ExpandableListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ExpandableListView nav_explistview;

    ArrayList<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        nav_explistview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_explistview);

        // preparing list data
        populateListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(listDataHeader, listDataChild,this);

        // setting list adapter
        nav_explistview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void populateListData() {


        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Heading 1");
        listDataHeader.add("Heading 2");
        listDataHeader.add("Heading 3");

        // Adding child data
        ArrayList<String> heading1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        heading1.add("Sub Item 1");
        heading1.add("Sub Item 2");
        heading1.add("Sub Item 3");
        heading1.add("Sub Item 4");

        ArrayList<String> heading2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        heading2.add("Sub Item 1");
        heading2.add("Sub Item 2");

        ArrayList<String> heading3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        heading3.add("Sub Item 1");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 2");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 3");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 4");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 5");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 6");
        heading3.add("Sub Item 7");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), heading1); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), heading2);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), heading3);
    }


}
```

So simply add an `ExpandableListView` inside `NavigationView` and initialise the `ExpandableListView` normally however you want, and you can get the expected result.

For further explanation on `ExpandableListView` view this article on [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

Comment: Let me know if you face any problem implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to add child elements [ExpandableListview](https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private String[] items;

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
    private NavigationManager mNavigationManager;

    private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mNavigationManager = FragmentNavigationManager.obtain(this);

        initItems();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
        mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
        mExpandableListTitle = new ArrayList(mExpandableListData.keySet());

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectFirstItemAsDefault();
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void selectFirstItemAsDefault() {
        if (mNavigationManager != null) {
            String firstActionMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionFilms)[0];
            mNavigationManager.showFragmentAction(firstActionMovie);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(firstActionMovie);
        }
    }

    private void initItems() {
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.film_genre);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        mExpandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, mExpandableListTitle, mExpandableListData);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                    .get(childPosition).toString();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedItem);

                if (items[0].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                    mNavigationManager.showFragmentAction(selectedItem);
                } else if (items[1].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                    mNavigationManager.showFragmentComedy(selectedItem);
                } else if (items[2].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                    mNavigationManager.showFragmentDrama(selectedItem);
                } else if (items[3].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                    mNavigationManager.showFragmentMusical(selectedItem);
                } else if (items[4].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                    mNavigationManager.showFragmentThriller(selectedItem);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported fragment type");
                }

                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```